# Can someone explain Hoare's partitioning scheme to me?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

just learned and implemented Hoare's partitioning scheme for quicksort in Java. Works as good as advertised lol, but I just have a couple questions about it. I tried looking up a youtube video on it, but didn't find any that explained it well to me.

I think in Hoare's actual partition, the pivot is supposed to be the first element, but I used the middle element as a pivot just in case the array is already sorted. I wrote some comments in the code on what Im a bit confused about. Mainly why `i` and `j` are set to 1 lower and 1 higher than `low` and `high` if theyre just incremented and decremented before checking the array.

```
public static void quicksort(int [] arr, int low, int high){
        if(low < high){
            int pivot = partition(arr, low, high);
            quicksort(arr, low, pivot);
            quicksort(arr, pivot+1, high);
        }
    }

        public static int partition(int [] arr, int low, int high){
        int i = low-1; //Why not just set i to low? 
        int j = high+1;// Why do you have to set it to high+1 and not high?
        int mid = low + (high-low)/2;
        int pivot = arr[mid];
        
        while(true){
            do {
                i++;
            } while(arr[i] < pivot);
            do {
                j--;
            } while(arr[j] > pivot); 
            
            if( i >= j) return j;
            swap(arr, i, j);
           
        } 
    }
```

But when I change the partitioning code to what it is below, it ends up running seemingly forever with bigger sized arrays, for example with 17 different numbers, and I need to manually stop it. The weird thing is that this code will work for smaller sized array, for example with 6 numbers in it, but not larger sized arrays. I can't manually go through the code for arrays with a lot of numbers because I get lost in the recursion calls.

```
 public static int partition(int [] arr, int low, int high){
        int i = low; 
        int j = high;
        int mid = low + (high-low)/2;
        int pivot = arr[mid];
        
        while(true){
           while(arr[i] < pivot){
               i++;
           }
           while(arr[j] > pivot){
               j--;
           } 
            
            if( i >= j) return j;
            swap(arr, i, j);
            
        } 
    }
```

So just hoping someone can let me know why the top one works perfectly and the bottom one doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important thing here is that *after* a swap has been performed of `a[i]` and `a[j]`, those two indexes should first be incremented/decremented before doing the next comparison with the pivot.

This doesn't happen in your second version.

This is however necessary. Imagine that at a certain moment both `a[i]` and `a[j]` are equal to the pivot value (because there are duplicate values). Then the swap will happen, but it will not change anything. What is worse, in your second version the comparison with the pivot value will again show that they are equal, and we're back to where we were: this becomes an infinite loop. If however there is at least one execution of `i++` and `j--` after a swap has occurred, such an infinite loop will not occur.

One way to ensure that `i++` and `j--` happen at least once after a swap, is to place them in a `do { } while` loop. And once you have made that choice, it is evident that the first time `i` must be one less than `low` and `j` one more than `high`.

Comment: I also have just one more question. After the partition, the element that was used as a pivot should be in the sorted index. However, when we call quicksort recursively the first time, why not use pivot-1 instead of pivot?

Comment: Indeed, it could be `pivot-1`. Care has to be taken: some implementations define `high` as the first index *after* the partition, while here it denotes the last index *within* the partition. In the first case you cannot do `pivot-1`, as then you would actually overlook one value.

Comment: Thanks again, I actually do have one more question. If you dont mind, can you tell me why we must return J as the new pivot? I know it won't work with i but I can't figure out exactly why it won't work

Comment: This is related with the `pivot-1` remark. There is only one way that `i > j` can be true (not equal): this happens when the pivot is a duplicate value, sitting side by side. As `i` gets to the left one, and `j` to the right, a (useless) swap will be done. Then `i` and `j` will cross over. Now let's assume the partition consisted just of these 2 duplicate values, so `high == low + 1`. Then at the end, `i == high` and `j == low`. If you return `i`, then the next recursive call with have the same `low` and `high`: thus infinite recursion. With `pivot-1` this does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to explain that process my way, because I fell that it is sometimes misunderstood.

The goal of the partition is to rearrange the array so that it is split in two subarrays with all elements in the "left" part not larger than those in the "right part". Beware that the predicate is "not larger", because "smaller" can be impossible to achieve, if all elements are equal.

It is also important to understand that after the partition process, no subarray can be empty, otherwise there is no progress and the (Quicksort) algorithm can loop endlessly.

Now the process is as follows:

- choose a pivot value. I say *value* rather than *element* because in fact any value can do, as long as the value is not outside the range of the elements (that would result in one subarray being empty);
- scan the array from the left and the right until you find a large element on the left and a small element on the right (wrt the pivot value*) or until the "pointers" meet;
- if no inverted pair could be found, you are done; otherwise, swap these two elements and  continue with the enclosed subarray.

In practice, the pivot value is taken to be the value of *some* element in the array (that ensures the non-emptiness condition). Ideally taking the median would be optimal, but getting the median is costly. A common heuristic is the "median of three". The mean could do as well, but it has a linear cost and only works for numerical values.

The scans are made one after the other. The left scan will certainly terminate *inside* the array. The right pointer may not pass the left one.

For debugging purposes, you can instrument the code so that it checks if the left and right pointers do not cross, if a swap is made with unequal pointers, and if the subarrays aren't empty in the end.

---

*What to do when an element has the value of the pivot is a subtlety: if you skip such elements to avoid them being swapped, there is a risk to reach the end of the array when all elements are equal.