# QuickSort algorithm with Hoare partitioning in C

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, quicksort, partition

I'm having an issue with this Quicksort algorithm:

```
void swap(int *x, int *y) {
    int tmp;

    tmp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = tmp;
}

int partition (int *arr, int min, int max) {
    int x = arr[min];
    int i = min - 1;
    int j = max + 1;

    while (1) {
        do {
            j--;
        } while (i < j && arr[j] < x);
        do {
            i++;
        } while (arr[i] > x);
        if  (i < j)
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        else
            return j + 1;
    }
}

void quickSort(int *arr, int inf, int sup) {
    if (arr) {
        if (inf < sup) {
            int pivot = partition(arr, inf, sup);
            //printf("pivot = %d", pivot);
            quickSort(arr, inf, pivot - 1);
            quickSort(arr, pivot + 1, sup);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int array[] = { 151, 153, 134, 137, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 158, 158, -1, -1, 133, 127, 158, 158 };

    int dim = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);
    quickSort(array, 0, dim - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It's supposed to return a descending sorted array but it doesn't for some reasons.

The input:(the rest of the 512 elements-long array is made of -1)

```
151 153 134 137 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 158 158 -1 -1 133 127 158 158
```

The output:

```
158 158 158 153 158 -1 151 134 137 133 127 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

Expected output:

```
158 158 158 158 153 151 137 134 133 127 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

I'm expecting the algorithm to return a descending sorted array.
I've tried to switch the input but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: @buben And where are there partitions merged?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow There's no merging with quicksort.

Comment: I've uploaded the post with a small main function calling the quicksort algorithm on a smaller array, but the issue still remains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to carefully debug your partition function. The return value should be `j`

```
int partition (int *arr,int min, int max){
    int x=arr[min];
    int i=min-1;
    int j=max+1;

    while (1) {
        do {
            j--;
        } while (i < j && arr[j] < x);
        do {
            i++;
        } while (arr[i] > x);
        if  (i < j)
            swap(&arr[i],&arr[j]);
        else
            return j;
    }
}
```

You can use gdb or any ide to debug the main flow and you can get the logic.
For quickSort func, you should use inf->pivot, pivot + 1 -> sup; instead of ignore your pivot index of array.

```
void quickSort(int *arr, int inf, int sup){
    if(arr){
        if(inf < sup){
            int pivot = partition(arr, inf, sup);
            //printf("pivot = %d", pivot);
            quickSort(arr, inf, pivot);
            quickSort(arr, pivot+1, sup);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it can help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort says that the Hoare partition scheme uses the element in the middle as the pivot element. So, `int x=arr[min];` should be `int x=arr[(min+max)/2];`.

Also, `partition` should `return j;`, not `j+1;`.

The first `quicksort` call should include the pivot element.

The `if` in the `quicksort` function was also incomplete.

Here is working code (at least with your example data):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *x, int *y){
    int tmp;

    tmp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = tmp;
}

int partition (int *arr,int min, int max){
    int x=arr[(min+max)/2];
    int i=min-1;
    int j=max+1;

    while (1) {
        while (arr[++i] > x);
        while (arr[--j] < x);

        if  (i >= j)
            return j;
        swap(&arr[i],&arr[j]);
    }
}

void quickSort(int *arr, int inf, int sup){

    if(arr){
        if(inf >= 0 && sup >= 0 && inf < sup){
            int pivot = partition(arr, inf, sup);
            //printf("pivot = %d\n", pivot);
            quickSort(arr, inf, pivot);
            quickSort(arr, pivot+1, sup);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int array[] = {151, 153, 134, 137, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 158, 158, -1, -1, 133, 127, 158, 158};

    int dim = sizeof(array)/ sizeof(int);
    quickSort(array, 0, dim-1);

    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/54W6j145e

Comment: thanks for the answer! it looks like the issues were indeed related to the returning value and the index of one of the quicksort function parameters as you said

Answer (score 0):

From the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) about Quicksort with Hoare partition scheme (emphasis mine):

> The original partition scheme described by Tony Hoare uses two pointers (indices into the range) that start at both ends of the array being partitioned, then move toward each other, until they detect an inversion: a pair of elements, one greater than the bound (Hoare's terms for the pivot value) at the first pointer, and one less than the bound at the second pointer; if at this point the first pointer is still before the second, these elements are in the wrong order relative to each other, and they are then exchanged. After this the pointers are moved inwards, and the search for an inversion is repeated; when eventually the pointers cross (the first points after the second), no exchange is performed; a valid partition is found, **with the point of division between the crossed pointers** (any entries that might be strictly between the crossed pointers are equal to the pivot and can be excluded from both sub-ranges formed). With this formulation it is possible that one sub-range turns out to be the whole original range, which would prevent the algorithm from advancing. Hoare therefore stipulates that at the end, **the sub-range containing the pivot element (which still is at its original position) can be decreased in size by excluding that pivot**, after (if necessary) exchanging it with the sub-range element closest to the separation; thus, termination of quicksort is ensured.

The same page shows an implementation in pseudo code:

```
// Sorts a (portion of an) array, divides it into partitions, then sorts those  
algorithm quicksort(A, lo, hi) is  
  if lo >= 0 && hi >= 0 && lo < hi then  
    p := partition(A, lo, hi)

    quicksort(A, lo, p)        // Note: the pivot is now included  
    quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)

// Divides array into two partitions
algorithm partition(A, lo, hi) is 
  // Pivot value
  pivot := A[ floor((hi - lo)/2) + lo ] // The value in the middle of the array

  // Left index
  i := lo - 1 

  // Right index
  j := hi + 1

  loop forever 
    // Move the left index to the right at least once and while the element at
    // the left index is less than the pivot
    do i := i + 1 while A[i] < pivot
    
    // Move the right index to the left at least once and while the element at
    // the right index is greater than the pivot
    do j := j - 1 while A[j] > pivot

    // If the indices crossed, return
    if i >= j then return j
    
    // Swap the elements at the left and right indices
    swap A[i] with A[j]
```

Unlike OP's code, the first recursive call to `quicksort` *includes* the pivot and `partition` returns `j` instead of `j + 1`.

Comment: thanks for the answer! it looks like the issues were related to the returning value and the index of one of the quicksort function parameters

Comment: That is not Hoare's original algorithm. The two whiles would be `A[i] <= pivot` and `A[j] >= pivot`, which meant boundary checks would be needed as well. Once one or both pointers reached a boundary, one element, usually the pivot would be swapped into place, and for random data, one or two elements would be excluded from later calls. In the case of all equal elements, the first call would end up with `i == hi` and `j == lo`, and return with just the one call. It was later than the compares were change from <= to < and from >= to >, eliminating boundary checks, but not excluding elements.

Comment: @rcgldr Interesting. Could you point me to some online reference, so that I can add it to the answer?

Comment: I added links to the original paper and to Hoare's improved version written in Algol at the end of the first paragraph of the history section of the WIki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#History

Comment: I converted the Algol code to C++ in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76888750/3282056) .